# Formal completion of a scalar extension

Tags: extension-field, tensor-products, laurent-series, localization, formal-completions

I would be grateful if someone could explain to me the error in the following computation.

Assume that M is a topologically complete $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module. Let $K:=\mathbb C((t))$ be the field of formal Laurent series. By definition, the completed tensor product $M\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K$ is given by

$$M\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K=invlim_{p, q\geq0}\frac{M}{(t)^p}\otimes\frac{K}{(t)^q}.$$

Now, since $K$ is a field, it follows that $K/(t)^q=0$ for every integer $q\geq0$. Hence, the above implies

$$M\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K=0.$$

This is clearly nonsense since in the special case $M=\mathbb C[[t]]$, we have $M\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K=K$, which is not $0$. However, I am unable to identify the mistake in my computations. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: $M\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K=K$ doesn't look right unless you are considering another kind of completion. The completion for the $t$-adic metric is not the same as the $t$-adic completion, namely $\varprojlim \Bbb{C}((t))/(t^n)=0$ whereas the metric completion of $\Bbb{C}((t))$ is $\Bbb{C}((t))$.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean the special case of $M=\mathbb C[[t]]$ in your comment? I would like to know what the $t$-adic completion of the algebraic tensor product $M\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K$ is? Is it $0$?

Comment: Sorry, could you please check your post. It is unreadable!

Comment: $t$ is a unit in the field $K$ so $K/(t^n)=0$

Comment: Do you mean that $K/(t^n)=0$ for every $n\geq0$ and hence, $M\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K=0$?  What would be then the metric completion of $M\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}K$?

Comment: Just to be sure that we are talking about the same thing. Is the definition given in the Stacks Project https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AMU the t-adic completion of the algebraic tensor product?

Comment: No, your link is about the topological completion, so it depends on which topology you choose on $K=\Bbb{C}((t))$. The $t$-adic topology is trivial (as $t^nK=K$ for all $n$) whereas the $t$-adic metric is not ($t^n \Bbb{C}[[t]]$ are a lot of open subgroups and $\varprojlim \Bbb{C}((t)) /t^n \Bbb{C}[[t]]\cong \Bbb{C}((t))$)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. In light of the above, what is meant then by the notation $K[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$? There are several possibilities-$K\hat\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathbb C[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$, $K\hat\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}\mathbb C[[t]][[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$ or $K\otimes_{\mathbb C[[t]]}\mathbb C[[t]][[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$?